# Create search form in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I created form to search in `lessons` table. In `..\templates\Lessons\find.php` is

```
<?= $this->Form->create($lesson, [
    'url' => [
        //'controller' => 'Lessons',
        'action' => 'results'
        ]
]) ?>
```

Than in `..\src\Controller\LessonsController.php` is defined

```
public function find()
{
    
}
```

How should I define `$lesson` variable in this function? If I visit url `../lessons/find`, I get: `Undefined variable: lesson [ROOT\templates\Lessons\find.php, line 16]`

In CakePHP Cookbook is example for an Add form: `$lesson = $this->Lessons->newEmptyEntity();` or example for an Edit form. Thanks for help

Comment: Try to leverage proper PRG pattern and https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use form with null context for search.
Form context is necessary only if want to add/edit records.